# Why can I change const variable in c++?

Tags: c++, constants, readonly

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(const int i)
{
    return i;
}

int f2(int i)
{
    i = 3;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    const int p = 1;
    int q = 2;
    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n", f(p), f(q), f2(p), f2(q));
}
```

In `f2` I am changing value even on `const` argument (`p`). How is it possible? Does `const` keyword have its meaning only for non-trivial (non-POD) types? (e.g. class and structs)? Or why the above compiled?

Comment: What `const` variable do you think is being modified? Note that `i` is a *copy* of `p` or `q`.

Comment: There are not any `const` variables being changed in the code provided.

Comment: You should add `printf("%i\n%i\n", p, q);` at the end of your code to see that you didn't modify any const variable.